# How to create multiple executables from a single .spec file?

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a program that I want to distribute to several customers but with their own name and logo and with different modes. Each customer need 3 different files and if I have 20 customers I would need 60 spec files. I have tried to create a .spec file that would create all in 1 compile but it just overwrites the same file and I end up with 1 file.

**Is it possible to create multiple executables with PyInstaller from a single .py using only 1 .spec file?**

I tried creating a list with all EXE, PYZ and so on but still only 1 executable gets created. In the 'build' folder created after i can see multiple .toc .pyz .pkg with different names. 00,01,02 and so on. It seems it is possible to do this but I'm missing something.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Python 3.6 and PyInstaller 3.5.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import glob
import os
import sys

block_cipher = None

companies_to_create = ["CustomerA", "CustomerB"]
modes = ["config", "service"]

# Testing list, static
list_PYZ = [None] * 4
list_EXE = [None] * 4
list_A = [None] * 4
app_nr = 0


for company in companies_to_create: 

  for mode in modes:

    # Changes mode in file to create
    with open("mainprogram/mode.py", "w") as f_mode:
      f_mode.write('mode="' + mode + '"')
    f_mode.close()

    # Changes company in file to create
    with open("mainprogram/company.py", "w") as f_company:
      f_company.write('company="' + company + '"')
    f_company.close()

    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules, collect_data_files
    from mainprogram.brands import company_app

    hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pubsub')

    list_A[app_nr] = Analysis(['mainprogram/mainprogram.py'],
                pathex=[],
                binaries=[],
                hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
                hookspath=[],
                runtime_hooks=[],
                excludes=['tkinter'],
                win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                win_private_assemblies=False,
                cipher=block_cipher)

    images = glob.glob("mainprogram/images/**/*", recursive=True)
    icons = glob.glob("mainprogram/icons/**/*", recursive=True)
    files = images + icons

    for f in files:
      if os.path.isfile(f):
        path = f.split('mainprogram/')[1]
        list_A[app_nr].datas += [((path, f, 'Data'))]


    list_PYZ[app_nr] = PYZ(list_A[app_nr].pure, list_A[app_nr].zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
    list_EXE[app_nr] = EXE(list_PYZ[app_nr],
              list_A[app_nr].scripts,
              list_A[app_nr].binaries,
              list_A[app_nr].zipfiles,
              list_A[app_nr].datas,
              name=company_app.exe_name,
              debug=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=False,
              console=False,
              icon='mainprogram/icons/' + company + '.ico')

    app_nr += 1
```